# Why is my Spring repository method returning a String instead of a UUID?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to get the IDs of all books with a specific tag ID. My query looks like this:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT book_id FROM book_tag bt WHERE bt.tag_id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
Set<UUID> findAllBookIdsByTagId(UUID tagId);
```

Books can be associated with any number of tags; the relationship is modeled like:

```java
@Entity(name = "Book")
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "UUID",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "book_tag",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")
    )
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();
}
```

However, when I put a breakpoint after a call to my repository method, I see that the value being returned is a set of strings, not a set of UUIDs. I don't even understand how this is possible. I thought it was just IntelliJ displaying it weirdly in the debugger, but no, evaluating `bookRepository.findAllBookIdsByTagId({tagId}).toArray()[0] instanceof UUID` was false, yet true for `instanceof String`.

The `id` property that comes back with the Book entity is correctly shown as a UUID, it's just when I query the ID directly that it comes back as a string.

Comment: Instead of my suggested answer and using a native query, you can also use the entity manager to execute a JPQL query, as it is more type-safe and aware of the entity mappings. But I have never seen someone doing it in practice :D

Comment: Ah okay--casting didn't work but using JPQL did! (`SELECT b.id FROM Tag t JOIN t.books b WHERE t.id= ?1`). Thank you!

Comment: Maybe removing the @Type() in your entity annotation might also help. We are using native queries to return Lists of UUIDs successfully (although, weirdly enough we have to cast them to varchar in the sql first) (on postgres)

Comment: So I will delete the suggested answer, as it didn't work with your issue.